# How to match and copy time-data from one matrix to another?

Tags: matlab, datetime, matrix

In MATLAB (R2015a), I have two large matrices that can be simplified as:

```
A = [ 24 10 830; 24 15 830; 150 17 945; 231 40 1130; 231 45 1130]
```

(note that in `A`, column 3 is the time for the event cataloged in column 1) and

```
B = [24 13; 150 29; 231 43]
```

How can I match and copy the time-data from column 3 in matrix `A`, to a matching and filtered event column in matrix `B`?

For example, I want the value 24 from first column in `B` to be matched with value 24 from first column in `A`, and then copy the corresponding time-data in `A`'s third column (for 24 it's 830, for 150 it's 945 etc.) into `B`. This should result into our new `B` with the time-data from `A`:

```
B = [24 13 830; 150 29 945; 231 43 1130]
```

I relatively new to MATLAB so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the location of the elements in the first row of `B` in the first row of `A` using the `ismember` function. And then use those locations to construct the new matrix.

```
[~,Locb] = ismember(B(:,1),A(:,1));
Bnew = [B A(Locb,3)]


Bnew =

          24          13         830
         150          29         945
         231          43        1130
```

This is a fast way that comes to my mind. There might be some singularities that needed to be checked more thoroughly.